# Cucumber examples reuse in different features/scenarios

Tags: csv, cucumber, scenarios

I've been using cucumber for awhile and I've stumbled upon a problem:

**Actual question:**

Is there a solution to import the examples from a single file/db using cucumber specifically as examples?
Or alternatively is there a way to define a variable while already in-step to be an example?
Or alternatively again, is there an option to send the examples as variables when I launch the feature file/scenario?

**The Problem:**

I have a couple of scenarios where I would like to use exactly the same examples, over and over again.

It sounds rather easy, but the examples table is very large (more specifically it contains all the countries in the world and their appropriate continents). Thus repeating it would be very troublesome, especially if the table needs changing (I will need to change all the instances of the table separately)

**Complication:**

I have a rerun function that knows when a specific example failed and reruns it after the test is done.

**Restrictions:**

I do not want to edit my rerun file

**Related:**

I've noticed that there is already an open discussion about importing it from csv here:
[Importing CSV as test data in Cucumber?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20955361/importing-csv-as-test-data-in-cucumber)

However that discussion is invalid to me because I have the rerun function that only knows to work only with examples, and the solution suggested there ruins that.

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSV and other external file systems with [QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf) using different [BDD syntax](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-syntax.html).

If you want to use cucumber steps or cucumber runner, you can use [QAF-cucumber](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber) and BDD2 (preferred) or Gherkin syntax. [QAF-cucumber](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber)  will enable external test data and other qaf features with cucumber.

Below is the example feature file uses BDD2 syntax can be run using [TestNG](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-configuration.html) or [Cucumber](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber#using-qaf-cucumber-with-cucumber-runner) runner.

```
Feature: feature uses external data file

@datafie:resources/${env}/testdata.csv
@regression 
Scenario:  Another scenario exploring different combination using data-provider
    Given a "${precondition}"
    When an event occurs
    Then the outcome should "${be-captured}"
```

**testdata.csv** file may look like:

```
TestcaseId,precondition,be-captured
123461,abc,be captured
123462,xyz,not be captured
```

You can run using [TestNG](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-configuration.html) or [Cucumber](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber#using-qaf-cucumber-with-cucumber-runner) runner. You can use any of [inbuilt data provider](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/maketest_data_driven.html#in-built-data-providers) or [custom](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd2.html#data-driven-scenario) as well.