# Reusable/Generic Examples table in Cucumber

Tags: cucumber, bdd, gherkin, cucumber-java, qaf

Is it possible for multiple scenarios to use the same Examples table?

So instead of having something like the following:

```
Scenario Outline: First Scenario
    Given I am viewing "<url>"
    Then I assert that the current URL "<url>"
    Examples:
      | url                |
      | https://google.com |
      | https://twitter.com|

  Scenario Outline: Second Scenario
    Given I am viewing "<url>" with route "</contactus>"
    Then I assert that "<url>" contains "contactus"
    Examples:
      | url                |
      | https://google.com |
      | https://twitter.com|
```

I can do something like

```
Scenario Outline: Reusable Example
    Examples:
      | url                |
      | https://google.com |
      | https://twitter.com|

  Scenario: First Scenario
    Given I am viewing "<url>"
    Then I assert that the current URL "<url>"

  Scenario: Second Scenario
    Given I am viewing "<url>" with route "</contactus>"
    Then I assert that "<url>" contains "contactus"
```

I found a [similar question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716186/cucumber-scenario-outline-reusing-examples-table), but merging all my scenarios in just one scenario is not an option for me. Since this question was posted in 2014, maybe there have been some advancements in the framework which I am not aware of :D

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might solve this with an `Scenario Outline` as both scenarios look similar for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [qaf-gherkin](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) where you can move examples in external file and use it with one or more scenario. With qaf your feature file may look like below:

```
Scenario Outline: First Scenario
   Given I am viewing "<url>"
   Then I assert that the current URL "<url>"
   Examples:{'datafile':'resources/testdata.txt'}

Scenario Outline: Second Scenario
Given I am viewing "<url>" with route "</contactus>"
Then I assert that "<url>" contains "contactus"
Examples:{'datafile':'resources/testdata.txt'}
```

And your datafile will look like:

```
url
https://google.com
https://twitter.com
```

Here is the [reference](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf/blob/master/test/resources/features/gherkin.feature).

Comment: Thank you for this, exactly what I needed. I was going through the documentation, am I right to assume that this will not work with Junit but will only work if we use testNG?

Comment: qaf is built upon TestNG, so when you are using qaf-bdd or qaf-gherkin you can consider that it's testng implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You might use a [Background](https://docs.cucumber.io/gherkin/reference/#background) to specify steps which are equal for all scenarios. (Have a look on the link for constraints)

A feature file might look like

```
Feature: use of reusable Given

  Background: Reusable Example
    Given I am viewing url
      | https://google.com |
    And a search phrase is entered in the search field

  Scenario: First Scenario
    And step for first scenario

  Scenario: Second Scenario
    And step for second scenario
```

implementing the glue code for the `Given`

```
@Given("^I am viewing url$")
public void iAmViewing(List<String> url) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("url = " + url);
}
```

**edit** After the question has been updated a `Scenario Outline` could work for both examples.

```
Feature: use of example

  Scenario Outline: First Scenario
    Given I am viewing "<host>" with path "<path>"
    Then I assert that the current URL is "<host><path>"

    Examples:
      | host                | path       |
      | https://google.com  | /          |
      | https://twitter.com | /contactus |
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, unfortunately the steps are not the same across the scenarios. Please see my updated question for further clarity :)